# Clear all content of cache folder in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel-5

I would like to ask how can I clear all the content of `cache` folder. `Cache::flush()` is only available in Laravel 5.1 and above but my current application is Laravel 5.0. I don't want to upgrade because I'm afraid to break the current system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use command line for delete cache ?

```
$ php artisan cache:clear
```

or clear cache by code

```
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```

Comment: I tried the `php artisan cache:clear` it works. But what I want is through code not through CLI so I tried `Artisan::call('cache:clear');` but it didn't work